# Text titles in table

Tags: tables, sectioning, titlesec

I'm trying to universally adjust my text titles via `titlesec` package. Though I cannot use those titles (`subparagraph` in my case) in a table - there are excessive vertical gaps I'm not able to get rid of:

**MWE:**

```
\documentclass[a4paper,fleqn,leqno]{article}
\usepackage{polyglossia}
\usepackage{color,pifont,fontspec}
\usepackage[top=1.5cm,bottom=0cm,left=2cm,right=2cm]{geometry}
\usepackage{changepage}
\usepackage{hyperref,titlesec}
\usepackage{array}
\pagestyle{empty}
\linespread{1}
\newcolumntype{C}[3]{@{\hspace*{#1}}>{\centering\arraybackslash}p{#2}@{\hspace*{#3}}}
\newcolumntype{R}[2]{>{\raggedleft\arraybackslash}p{#1}@{\hspace*{#2}}}
\newcolumntype{L}[2]{@{\hspace*{#1}}>{\raggedright\arraybackslash}p{#2}}
\newcolumntype{"}[1]{@{\vrule width #1}}
\makeatletter\newcommand{\ohline}[1]{\noalign {\ifnum 0=`}\fi\hrule height #1\futurelet\reserved@a\@xhline}\makeatletter
\newlength\savedwidth
\newcommand{\ocline}[2]{\noalign{\global\savedwidth\arrayrulewidth\global\arrayrulewidth #1}\cline{#2}\noalign{\vskip\arrayrulewidth}\noalign{\global\arrayrulewidth\savedwidth}}
\setmainfont{Cambria}
\titleformat{\subparagraph}{\Large\scshape}{}{0pt}{}[]
\titlespacing{\subparagraph}{0pt}{0pt}{0pt}[0pt]
\newenvironment{odstavec}{}{\vspace{25pt}}
\begin{document}

text
\subparagraph{Paragraf}
\begin{odstavec}
text
\end{odstavec}

\begin{tabular}{|L{0pt}{5cm}|L{0pt}{5cm}|}
\hline
\subparagraph{Paragraph} & \subparagraph{Paragraph} \\
\hline
Text in table & Text in table \\
\hline
Text in table & Text in table \\
\hline
\end{tabular}

\end{document}
```

[image: Titles in table - excessive vertical gaps]
I just have to adjust the titles in a table manually - one by one.
How can I use the title's variable (by that I mean e.g. `\subparagraph{}`) in a table without vertical gaps?

Comment: Why do you use `\subparagraph` inside a `tabular`? Is there a particular reason? On the other hand you can just change the font.

Comment: My intention is to define some title's variable (which is for example `\subparagraph{}` adjusted with `titlesec` package) that I can use everywhere. I would like to avoid changing fonts for each title manually unless it's last option.

Comment: @user46581: There remains that sectioning commands are not meant for use in tables. They insert vertical spacing before and after them, hence the vertical gaps.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It would be best to just define a new macro to format column titles, separate from the sectioning commands:

```
\documentclass[a4paper,fleqn,leqno]{article}
\usepackage{titlesec}
\usepackage{array}
\pagestyle{empty}
\newcolumntype{L}[2]{@{\hspace*{#1}}>{\raggedright\arraybackslash}p{#2}}
\titleformat{\subparagraph}{\Large\scshape}{}{0pt}{}[]
\titlespacing{\subparagraph}{0pt}{0pt}{0pt}[0pt]
\newenvironment{odstavec}{}{\vskip 25pt}
\newcommand*\tabsubparagraph[1]{\textsc{\Large #1}}
\begin{document}

  text
  \subparagraph{Paragraf}
  \begin{odstavec}
    text
  \end{odstavec}

  \begin{tabular}{|L{0pt}{5cm}|L{0pt}{5cm}|}
    \hline
    \tabsubparagraph{Paragraph} & \tabsubparagraph{Paragraph} \\
    \hline
    Text in table & Text in table \\
    \hline
    Text in table & Text in table \\
    \hline
  \end{tabular}

\end{document}
```

[image: tabular column titles]